# Setspace package changes behavior of \abovedisplayskip

Tags: spacing, lengths, setspace

When using the `spacing` environment from the `setspace` package, it appears that rubber lengths in `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip` are being ignored.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\flushbottom
\begin{document}
%\begin{spacing}{1.0}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{12pt plus 1000pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{12pt plus 1000pt}%
\lipsum[1]
\par
\lipsum[2]
%
\[a^2+b^2=c^2\]
%
\lipsum[3]
\par
\lipsum[4]
%
\[
\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g\\h\\i\end{array}
\]
%\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

My MWE is designed such that the second fomula with the very tall array forces an unpleasant page break. Due to the big rubber lengths in `\abovedisplayskip` and `\belowdisplayskip`, lots of space is introduced around the first formula instead of spreading the paragraphs. This behavior is as expected. (Side question: Why does it not work, when I set the lengths before `\begin{document}`?)

[image]

However, when I add the two commented out lines that begin and end the `spacing` environment, then for some reason the rubber lenghts are ignored. When I output the value of the length, the rubber is there, but the space just doesnt't want to stretch.

[image]

This happens irrespective of the stretch value passed to the `spacing` environment. (A spread of 1.0 is obviously nonsensical and just for illustration). What can I do to correct this behavior?

Comment: While looking for the source of the `setspace` package, I stubled over [this](https://github.com/rf-latex/setspace/issues/1) issue that seems related to my problem. Adding `\setdisplayskipstretch{}` as suggested there, indeed restores the stretching behavior before and after display math. However, this also disables the automatic stretching of space around equations together with the line spreading, which then has to be done manually. Hence, this is only a partial solution.

Comment: If I remember correctly, each `lipsum` paragraph ends with `\par`, and a paragraph break before a display environment wreaks havoc with the vertical spacing.  That may not be the problem with your actual project, but it would cause the results of a test to be unreliable.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know that. The MWE is now updated to use the `nopar` option of the `lipsum` package to get rid of the `\par`. The problem persists without change, however.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As to *why*, the answer is easy: the `setspace` package does

```latex
\everydisplay\expandafter{%
  \the\everydisplay
  \abovedisplayskip \displayskipstretch\abovedisplayskip
  \belowdisplayskip \displayskipstretch\belowdisplayskip
  \abovedisplayshortskip \displayskipstretch\abovedisplayshortskip
  \belowdisplayshortskip \displayskipstretch\belowdisplayshortskip
}
```

which means that stretch and shrink components are killed, if `\displayskipstretch` has a numeric value. Without `\begin{spacing}{1.0}`, the eventual expansion of `\displayskipstretch` is empty, so the killing doesn't happen.

We need to remove the faulty bits and reconstruct `\everydisplay`. The following assumes that stretch and shrink components are finite.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[nopar]{lipsum}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newcommand{\addstretchshrink}[1]{%
  \if\relax\displayskipstretch\relax
    % there is no factor, don't add plus and minus
  \else
    plus \displayskipstretch\gluestretch#1
    minus \displayskipstretch\glueshrink#1
  \fi
}
\def\fix#1\abovedisplayskip#2\displayskipstretch\belowdisplayshortskip#3\fix{%
  \everydisplay{#1#3
    \abovedisplayskip = \displayskipstretch\abovedisplayskip \addstretchshrink\abovedisplayskip
    \belowdisplayskip = \displayskipstretch\belowdisplayskip \addstretchshrink\belowdisplayskip
    \abovedisplayshortskip = \displayskipstretch\abovedisplayshortskip \addstretchshrink\abovedisplayshortskip
    \belowdisplayshortskip = \displayskipstretch\belowdisplayshortskip \addstretchshrink\belowdisplayshortskip
  }%
}
\expandafter\fix\the\everydisplay\fix

\flushbottom

\begin{document}
\begin{spacing}{1.0}
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{12pt plus 1000pt}%
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{12pt plus 1000pt}%
\lipsum[1]
\par
\lipsum[2]
%
\[a^2+b^2=c^2\]
%
\lipsum[3]
\par
\lipsum[4]
%
\[
\begin{array}{c}a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g\\h\\i\end{array}
\]
\end{spacing}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this totally makes sense. I didn't know about `\gluestretch` and `\glueshrink` before, that was the missing part for me. Do I get it right, that your `\fix` basically cuts out the relevant part of `\everydisplay` between `#1` and `#3`, then re-inserts `#1` and `#3` but discards everything in between?

Comment: @ranguwud Yes, that's necessary otherwise those settings would cancel stretch and shrink. There's room for improvement, though.